# A way to list all running dbus session buses?

Tags: d-bus

Is there a convenient or canonical way to find the address of every session bus currently running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically there isn't a reliable/official way to know whether a socket address corresponds to a DBUS session bus or not because the naming scheme for DBUS session bus addresses is private to the implementation: you're only supposed to launch `dbus-daemon` and opaquely use the address it chooses for itself. However, I can observe on my system that `dbus-daemon` appears to always use bus addresses of the same form. So something like this should do it:

```
netstat -an | grep @/tmp/dbus- | awk '{ print $NF }' | sort | uniq
```